# iPhone - Electronic Fund Transfer(EFT) system

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, ios5

I am about to develop a new iPhone application in which I need to pay for some bills. I need to use Electronic Fund Transfer(EFT) system to make the payment. I have no idea in integrating the EFT method to the application. Share some useful ideas or links where can I get some ideas regarding EFT and the work flow.

Comment: Sorry to sound rude, but if you have no idea on how to integrate a payment system are you really sure you are up to the task of creating a secure app that handles peoples money?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have posted here to gather idea. I am looking for a blog or resource where I can get a proper work flow. I will release the application after a proper and real time testing. Thanks, your reply will make my application much secured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for secure transaction you can use paypal and paypal also provided ios supported api for it they handle all details in a web view then getting details they return to app and do the transactions instead of these if you use any thing i think apple will reject the app or will ask you to implement the In App Purchase (IAP).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Will apple accept my application if I use PayPal API?

Comment: this link specify apple accept this is the paypal app.http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/paypal/id283646709?mt=8 download the app and you can check what it do and what is your requirements and does it's api support your need just check it out.

Comment: Thank you Ballu. Will check it.

Comment: Will apple reject my app, if I use CC Avenue?

Comment: i think these thing you should do on the iphone browser